# Mule Dataweave : There is no variable named 'lookup'

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to use the lookup function in a dataweave script but I am getting the error from the question "There is no variable named 'lookup'". Has anyone come across this and know how to fix it?

I am using Mule 3.7.1

**Update**
This works at runtime, but won't give a preview, is there a way to make a preview work when using lookup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible during designtime in the current versions of Mule 3.7.x / 3.8.x and the current versions of Studio.

The invocation of the flow you are calling via DataWeave's lookup function only happens at execution time. I had a look in latest 3.8.5, you won't see the error but null as a value for the lookup.

Metadata population via DataSense from the flow that will be called doesn't come through via this function in Dataweave.

Debugging may also gave you a hard time in 3.7.x but improved in 3.8.x, so you can see the behaviour and values to and from the flow you execute the lookup to.

Comment: Thank you for the information, was this information available on a Mulesoft website anywhere?

Comment: No, this is from experience ;)